# Tracking last login and last visit

Tags: plugins, login

I'm using the code below to track when a user last logs in. I'm realizing though that if they checked the `Remember Me` option, this won't track their last **visit**.

```
// Catch the time they login and save it
function set_last_login($login) {
  $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);
  update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql') );
}
add_action('wp_login', 'set_last_login');

// Function to display the time
function get_last_login($user_id) {
  $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', true);
  $date_format = get_option('date_format') . ' ' . get_option('time_format');
  $the_last_login = mysql2date($date_format, $last_login, false);
  return $the_last_login;
}
```

In addition to the working code above for tracking login, I'm looking to see when the user was last active **if they are already logged in**.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new entry for the user meta data and update it on every admin pageload.

Put the following in your theme's `functions.php` or maybe wrap it into a plugin:

```
function update_last_action_time() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_action_time', current_time('mysql'));
}
add_action('admin_init', 'update_last_action_time');
```

Of course, you could refine this (and thus lower the overhead) by restricting this to certain pages, for instance, the dashboard only.

**// Edit**: you should use [`update_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) instead of the deprecated [`update_usermeta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_usermeta).

**// Edit**, again

In case you want to track users on the front-end, put this code in your desired template:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_action_time', current_time('mysql'));
}
```

Again, to lower the overhead, I'd prefer putting this **not** into the `footer.php` file. I'd rather take `home.php` (if you have one), or check for particular requests (e.g., your *home* page, meaning: `home_url() == 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`). But as said before (meaning: below ;)), the overhead is, of course, *okay* when using it nonetheless in `footer.php`.

Comment: This is a good start for me, thanks! I restrict admin access, but perhaps if they go to their member page, or even the front page I'd track it. I'll have to contemplate this one for a bit to make sure I'm not adding too much overhead. Thanks for the `update_user_meta` catch too.

Comment: Do you think adding something like this to `wp_footer` would add a lot of overhead since it's just writing a quick field?

Comment: Well, `wp_footer` is the wrong hook, since you only want to track logged in users. Keep it either hooked in `admin_init` (as stated above) or restrict it to certain admin pages.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I had a brainfart. I meant the footer of my theme. Not hooking it in, but running something like `<?php update_last_action_time(); ?>` when the footer of the theme is called. (Of course, adding a little more heavy lifting to the function.) I'm concerned about overhead, but thinking this would be minimal?

Comment: Of course, the overhead is minimal, I just named it _overhead_, because most of the time you'll be updating the value while you actually don't need it. That's why I stated to restrict it to your needs. But again, when talking about the footer of your theme, it is the **front-end** you're talking about. If you want to track logged-in users on the back-end (meaning admin sites), then put the code into the `functions.php` (hooked into `admin_init`, as mentioned before). For tracking logged-in users reading your website, put it in the footer for instance, but check `if (is_user_ logged_in()) ...`.

Comment: Exactly what my thought was. Like you, I'd prefer `admin_init`, but like I said, I'm blocking wp-admin to subscribers (and that's what my site users are), so no sense it putting it there. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you are (primarily) tracking subscribers (without access to wp-admin). I updated my answer, and added a bit of what I said/meant before.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code which creates a function `display_last_login` that retrieves the current user's ID, fetches the last login timestamp from the transient storage, and displays it on the screen.

```
function display_last_login() {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;
$last_login = get_transient( 'user_last_login_' . $user_id );
if ( false === $last_login ) {
    $last_login = __( 'Never', 'textdomain' );
} else {
    $last_login = date( 'j F Y, H:i:s', $last_login );
}
echo '<p>Last Login: ' . $last_login . '</p>';
```

}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'set_user_last_login' );
function set_user_last_login( $user_login ) {
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_login );
$user_id = $user->ID;
set_transient( 'user_last_login_' . $user_id, time() );
}