# Save users last visited blogs within whole network

Tags: wp-user-query

I have a big network with subdomains (many of which use domains).
I thought about solving this problem with cookies but after some research I don't think that crossdomain cookies is a best Idea.

So I imagine this happing by saving in users meta some array of blogs and then displaying them on main page.

I came across **update_user_meta()** which is very handy in my case.

```
global $blog_id;
$current_blog_details = get_blog_details( array( 'blog_id' => $blog_id ) );

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs',  $current_blog_details->blogname);
}
```

I save this function inside admin-bar.php so every blog shares this code.
Now I want to remake this code to use save 5 last visited blogs as an array and then get those values and display on some place.

First question would be how to save 5 sites.
I guess update is not my case no?

Comment: There are interesting code and discussion in this Q&A: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/92260. The tracking that you want is not clear, maybe the link can help to update your Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your attantion, I made it working with **update_user_meta**
Here is my little function I wrote

```
global $blog_id;
$current_blog_details = get_blog_details( array( 'blog_id' => $blog_id ) );

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $last_visited_blogs = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs',true);
    if($last_visited_blogs) {
        if (end($last_visited_blogs) != $current_blog_details->blogname) {
            if (count($last_visited_blogs) < 5) {
                array_push($last_visited_blogs, $current_blog_details->blogname);
            } else {
                array_shift($last_visited_blogs);
                array_push($last_visited_blogs, $current_blog_details->blogname);
            }
            update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs', $last_visited_blogs);
        }
    } else {
        $last_visited_blogs = array($current_blog_details->blogname);
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs', $last_visited_blogs);
    }
    $last_visited_blogs_reversed = array_reverse($last_visited_blogs);
    foreach($last_visited_blogs_reversed as $key => $value) {
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
            'id'    => $value,
            'title' => $value,
            'href'  => admin_url( 'didiyle.php' ),
        ) );
    }
}
```

I use it in my admin-bar, if you need you can use it anywhere, needs a little modifications though